# Not getting battery status at the beginning of the application

Tags: android

I'm trying to control battery levels and power connection on my application with some listeners, but for some reason they are not getting updated neither at the beginning of the application. Is there any way of doing it manually?

class PhoneStatusService

```
private BroadcastReceiver mPowerConnectedReceiver;

private BroadcastReceiver mPowerDisconnectedReceiver;

private BroadcastReceiver mNormalPowerReceiver;

private BroadcastReceiver mLowPowerReceiver;

private static boolean sIsBatteryCharging = false;

private static boolean sIsBatteryLevelOk = true;
```

onCreate()

```
    mPowerConnectedReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
            PhoneStatusService.this.setChargingStatus(true);
        }
    };
    mPowerDisconnectedReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
            PhoneStatusService.this.setChargingStatus(false);
        }
    };
    mNormalPowerReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
            PhoneStatusService.this.setBatteryLevel(true);
        }
    };
    mLowPowerReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
            PhoneStatusService.this.setBatteryLevel(false);
        }
    };
    this.registerReceiver(mPowerConnectedReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED));
    this.registerReceiver(mPowerDisconnectedReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED));
    this.registerReceiver(mNormalPowerReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_OKAY));
    this.registerReceiver(mLowPowerReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW));
```

Comment: its working after starting your application ? means after few mins or seconds ?

Comment: Better you can use Application Class for registering this Broadcast Receivers

Comment: So you should register the broadcast receivers in Application class.

Comment: Bad idea that doesn't fit my architecture. I solved it by getting the status once and doing a callback.